# This CMD code checks for x32 or x64 , but it does not function?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 64-bit

so I'm creating a LEGIT Office 2013 activator , it uses our Genuine key and runs /act script to activate it.

So in order to check for a x32 or x64 bit of Office , I made the cmd search for a file called ospp.vbs , if it was found in x86 then it is x32 , if it was found in program files then it is x64. but if it wasn't found inside x32 it proceeds to the next step , but it tells me /microsoft was not expected , and then it closes?
Here's my CMD file:

```
@echo off
echo.Microsoft Office 2013 Activator
pause >nul
cls
NET SESSION >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    goto :Start
) ELSE (
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.           ERROR: YOU ARE NOT AN ADMIN!
ECHO.   PLEASE RUN THIS TOOL AS AN ADMIN IN ORDER FOR IT TO WORK PROPERLY
ECHO.              PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT THE TOOL
PAUSE >NUL
EXIT
)

:Start
type "C:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\office15\ospp.vbs" >NUL 2>NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
echo.x32 Office 2013 on x64 Machine Found.
echo.Why did you get x32 Office on an x64 Machine?
echo.Preparing to activate...
pause >nul
cls
goto :x32
) ELSE (
goto :x64check
)
:x64check
type "C:\program files\microsoft office\office15\ospp.vbs" >NUL 2>NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo.x64 Office 2013 on x64 Machine Found 
echo.or
echo.x32 Office 2013 on x32 Machine Found
echo.Preparing to Activate...
pause >nul
cls
goto :x64
) ELSE (
echo.Office 2013 Could not be found on this machine...
echo.Are you sure Office 2013 is installed?
echo.If it is installed , search for ospp.vbs in C:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office 15\
pause >nul
cls
)

:x32
cd "C:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\Office15\"
cls
cscript ospp.vbs /remhst
cls
cscript ospp.vbs /act
cls
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
pause >nul
echo Check the Above to see if Activation succeded or press any key to open winword and check it maunally.
pause >nul
start winword

:x64
cd "C:\program files\microsoft office\Office15\"
cls
cscript ospp.vbs /remhst
cls
cscript ospp.vbs /act
cls
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
pause >nul
echo Check the Above to see if Activation succeded or press any key to open winword and check it maunally.
pause >nul
start winword
```

can you please tell me where my problem is? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that error message is this line:

```
echo.If it is installed , search for ospp.vbs in C:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office 15\
```

The close parentheses `)` is being interpreted as the end of the scope for the `else`.  Escape the parentheses when using them as literals and they are not contained within quotations.

```
echo.If it is installed , search for ospp.vbs in C:\program Files ^(x86^)\Microsoft Office\Office 15\
```